# Parsing Domainname From URL In PHP

Tags: php, url, domain-name

How I can parse a domain from URL in PHP? It seems that I need a country domain database.

Examples:

> http://mail.google.com/hfjdhfjd/jhfjd.html -> google.com
>   http://www.google.bg/jhdjhf/djfhj.html -> google.bg
>   http://www.google.co.uk/djhdjhf.php -> google.co.uk
>   http://www.tsk.tr/jhjgc.aspx -> tsk.tr
>  http://subsub.sub.nic.tr/
>   -> nic.tr
>  http://subsub.sub.google.com.tr -> google.com.tr
>  http://subsub.sub.itoy.info.tr -> itoy.info.tr

Can it be done with whois request?

Edit: There are few domain names with `.tr` (`www.nic.tr`, `www.tsk.tr`) the others are as you know: `www.something.com.tr`, `www.something.org.tr`

Also there is no `www.something.com.bg`, `www.something.org.bg`. They are `www.something.bg` like the Germans' `.de`

But there are `www.something.a.bg`, `www.something.b.bg` thus `a.bg`, `b.bg`, `c.bg` and so on. (`a.bg` is like `co.uk`)

There on the net must be list of these top domain names.

Check how is coloured the url `http://www.agrotehnika97.a.bg/` in Internet Explorer.
Check also

```
www.google.co.uk<br>
www.google.com.tr<br>
www.nic.tr<br>
www.tsk.tr
```

Comment: Note, that *co.uk*, *com.tr* and *info.tr* itself are completely valid domains/host names, and all those are *not* top level domains. As such `google` in `google.co.uk` is *just* a subdomain of `co.uk`. Given that you can freely combine nearly everything, you probably won't be able to make a complete table for that..

Comment: @poke, I saw the list in a web site. Firefox was/is using the list of that website. But I do not remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain is stored in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

EDIT: I believe this returns the whole domain. To just get the top-level domain, you could do this:

```
// Add all your wanted subdomains that act as top-level domains, here (e.g. 'co.cc' or 'co.uk')
// As array key, use the last part ('cc' and 'uk' in the above examples) and the first part as sub-array elements for that key
$allowed_subdomains = array(
    'cc'    => array(
        'co'
    ),
    'uk'    => array(
        'co'
    )
);

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$parts = explode('.', $domain);
$top_level = array_pop($parts);

// Take care of allowed subdomains
if (isset($allowed_subdomains[$top_level]))
{
    if (in_array(end($parts), $allowed_subdomains[$top_level]))
        $top_level = array_pop($parts).'.'.$top_level;
}

$top_level = array_pop($parts).'.'.$top_level;
```

Comment: This isn't quite what ilhan is after.

Comment: It still doesn't work even after the edit ;-). It does not deal with the google.co.uk case, as this would return 'co.uk'.

Comment: Well, how should a computer know whether a domain is meant to be a subdomain or not then without manually adding all examples like `co.uk`, `co.cc` and so on? I'll try to edit mine, though.

Comment: Better now? I added an option to manually specify these exceptions.

Comment: I guess you can use the list at http://publicsuffix.org/list and convert it to this format (I'd suggest using a script) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_url()` to split it up and get what you want.
Here's an example...

```
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=google&btnG=Google+Search&meta=lr%3D&aq=&oq=dasd';
    print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Will echo...

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.google.com
    [path] => /search
    [query] => hl=en&source=hp&q=google&btnG=Google+Search&meta=lr%3D&aq=&oq=dasd
)
```

Comment: I did the same mistake in the beginning. He only wants `google.com`, though.

Comment: I see. Fair enough -- he can `preg_match()` to get the rest. Assuming `$url_split` is the parsed URL -- this can be done with... `preg_match('/www\.?([\w\-\.]+)([a-z\.]+)/i', $url_split['host'], $matches)` -- he can then use `$matches[1].$matches[2]` to fetch the host without the first domain. Problem with this though, is you can never predict how far the subdomain goes -- it could be `sub1.sub2.domain.co.uk` -- this would fetch `sub2.domain.co.uk`, not `domain.co.uk`

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you'll need a list of all suffixes used after a domain name.
http://publicsuffix.org/list/ provides an up-to-date (or so they claim) of all suffixes in use currently.
The list is actually [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/src/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) 
Now the idea would be for you to parse up that list into a structure, with different levels split by the dot, starting by the end levels:

so for instance for the domains:
com.la
com.tr
com.lc

you'd end up with:

```
[la]=>[com]
[lc]=>[com]
```

etc...

Then you'd get the host from base_url (by using parse_url), and you'd explode it by dots. and you start matching up the values against your structure, starting with the last one:

so for google.com.tr you'd start by matching tr, then com, then you won't find a match once you get to google, which is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Regex and parse_url() aren't solution for you.

You need package that uses [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only in this way you can correctly extract domains with two-, third-level TLDs (co.uk, a.bg, b.bg, etc.). I recomend use [TLD Extract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).

Here example of code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('http://subsub.sub.google.com.tr');
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return (string) 'google.com.tr'
```