# PHP website domainname

Tags: php, dns, header, http-host, server-name

I've seen some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327777/parsing-domainname-from-url-in-php) which show that the current website domain is accessible from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. The HTTP_HOST is an HTTP header and thus the user is free to change it. There is no reason to believe it's accurate. The SERVER_NAME doesn't change in my situation, because I use an domain alias that does change the domain but not the SERVER_NAME. What's best to do in this situation?

Comment: What is your desired results? Displaying the servername value of the matching virtualhost or what the user thinks the site is?

Comment: What's best to do, to achieve what?

Comment: I want to find the find the value of the matching virtualhost (to determine which language to choose)

Answer (score 1):

Although a user is free to change `HTTP_HOST`, they would hardly reach your site in this case.

Anyway, I see no problem in this ability to change. Okay, even if I set this header to `some.bad.bad.words` - whom it would harm?

Comment: Well, I then can't confirm what site the user's on.

Comment: Well, don't process that request at all. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could trust on your host name. Try with:

```
$hostname = exec('echo $HOSTNAME');
```

Comment: ANY environment variable can have only 2 sources, already mentioned in the question. It can be either "trusted" hardcoded and thus useless value, or user-supplied "untrusted" one.

Comment: I guess you're wrong. If the problem is that HTTP_HOST in unreliable, the method that I suggested is ok because point on the local hostname value. This is not alterable by the user request. In my cases, the solution reported worked perfectly. Regards.